# Duplicate/Overlap - T/SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Below is an example table.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (ID int, Name varchar(50), LiveDate Date, LiveTime time(7), Duration_Seconds int)

INSERT INTO @Temp (ID, Name, LiveDate, LiveTime, Duration)
SELECT 1, 'ABC', '2013-08-19', '00:01:00.0000000', 300
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ABC', '2013-08-19', '00:01:00.0000000', 300
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'DEF', '2013-08-19', '00:01:00.0000000', 300
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'DEF', '2013-08-19', '00:03:00.0000000', 300
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'GHI', '2013-08-19', '00:01:00.0000000', 300
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'GHI', '2013-08-19', '00:01:00.0000000', 300
UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'GHI', '2013-08-19', '00:03:00.0000000', 300
UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'GHI', '2013-08-19', '00:09:00.0000000', 300
UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'GHI', '2013-08-20', '00:06:00.0000000', 300
UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'JKL', '2013-08-19', '00:01:00.0000000', 300
UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'MNO', '2013-08-19', '00:01:00.0000000', 300

SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  Name, LiveDate, LiveTime) > 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS Duplicate 
FROM @Temp
```

Now, the output that I desire is the following.

```
/*
Desired Output
ID  Name    LiveDate        Livetime            Duration_Seconds    Duplicate   OverLap
1   ABC     2013-08-19      00:01:00.0000000    300                 Yes         No
2   ABC     2013-08-19      00:01:00.0000000    300                 Yes         No
3   DEF     2013-08-19      00:01:00.0000000    300                 No          Yes
4   DEF     2013-08-19      00:03:00.0000000    300                 No          Yes
5   GHI     2013-08-19      00:01:00.0000000    300                 Yes         Yes 
6   GHI     2013-08-19      00:01:00.0000000    300                 Yes         Yes
7   GHI     2013-08-19      00:03:00.0000000    300                 No          Yes
8   GHI     2013-08-19      00:09:00.0000000    300                 No          No
9   GHI     2013-08-20      00:06:00.0000000    300                 No          No
10  JKL     2013-08-19      00:01:00.0000000    300                 No          No
11  MNO     2013-08-19      00:01:00.0000000    300                 No          No
*/
```

How may I go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

I am unsure of how to find Overlap.

For Overlap to be Yes/True/1, the Name and Date has to be the same. 
Then, we have to look at the time and duration. 
  Let's say for GHI, time = 12:01 for ID 5 and 6 and 12:03 for ID 7. 
  But according to the duration, which is 300 seconds OR 5 mins, since 12:03 is within 5 mins from 12:01, I want to mark Overlap = Yes/True/1 for those three records.

Consider LiveTime as Start Time. Duration_Seconds as total time the record was Live. 
So GHI ID 5 & 6  LiveTime = 12:01 AM and lasted for 300 seconds (5 minutes). So It went live at 12:01 AM and was dead at 12:06 AM. 
GHI ID 7 went live at 12:03 AM with SAME Name and Date. But it should not have since we already have record Live from 12:01 AM to 12:06 AM with same Name and Date. Therefore, all GHI are marked as Overlap = Yes/True/1

Hope this helps you understand what I am trying to do.

THX

Comment: Updated the last record...thx to whoever pointed it out. Also, why a downvote?

Comment: You should post what you tried, what didn't work, etc.  Basically, show that you're not using StackOverflow as a place to get your work done for you.

Comment: And define the rules.  Example is good but don't expect us to infer the rules (basis).

Comment: Sorry guys, updated my code...I am getting Duplicates...not the Overlap. Updating my initial post for better rules.

Comment: Updated my rule for Overlap.

Comment: Why is Overlap 'No' for ABC, but 'Yes' for all GHI?  Only the last record of GHI is overlapping, right?

Comment: Overlap = NO for ABC because they are duplicate...exact match. If the LiveTime is the only thing that's different and according to the Duration_Seconds, if it does fall within the livetime+duration period of other same Name & Date fields, it's and overlap. If one record of the bunch is overlap, all of them are marked as overlap as we don't know which record was actually valid..therefor, all GHI will be Overlap and just first two will be duplicate.. Does this help?

Comment: Updated answer to handle all scenarios in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, there might be a simpler way:

```
;WITH cte AS (  SELECT *,
                    CASE
                        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  Name, LiveDate, LiveTime) > 1 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END AS Duplicate 
                FROM @Temp)
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,CASE WHEN b.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'Overlap'
FROM  cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON   a.NAME = b.NAME
  AND a.LiveDate = b.LiveDate
  AND ((b.LiveTime > a.Livetime  AND b.LiveTime < DATEADD(SECOND,a.Duration_Seconds,a.LiveTime))
       OR (a.LiveTime > b.Livetime  AND a.LiveTime < DATEADD(SECOND,b.Duration_Seconds,b.LiveTime)))
```

You might have to adjust the `JOIN` criteria if the above doesn't work for all instances of overlap.

Comment: Thanks Goat, I found duplicate with just a slight different syntex...although same logic as yours. Thanks, for pointing out another way of doing this. Will definitely keep this in mind. Updated rules for Overlap in my original post.

Comment: Umm...dude/lady...this is just amazing...I will spend next half hour trying to understand what you are doing here...THANK YOU SO MUCH "Meeh, meeh"

Comment: No problem, the basic idea is that to compare the time field between multiple rows you need to join the table to itself, if a record joins, there is overlap for that Name/Date combination.

Comment: thanks, trying diff scenarios. I added a few more records (ID 8 - 11). I am getting Overlap = 1 for ID 8 where it should be 0 (it's outside 12:01 AM - 12:06 AM window (or 12:03 AM to 12:08 AM window). will look into your join condition and see if I can figure out a way to get that logic working.

Comment: Updated to accommodate added scenarios.